# how to use the schedule method

Tags: java

How shall I use Timer class schedule method?My requirement is that the task that I will write in the schedule method should run once a day.Can anybody please write the required signature for the method?

Comment: In what environment is this running? Server-app our standalone desktop app? Does your app reboots? Maybe you should consider using Quartz which is designed for job scheduling with persistence and all...

Comment: Would this task be better suited to the windows task scheduler?

Comment: J2EE servlet jsp.I am intantiating the .java class in servlets init() method

Comment: Definitely go for Quartz then.

Comment: I am completely unaware of that.can we stick to Timer class

Comment: Then you could just use scheduleAtFixedRate(task , firstTimeOfExecution, period); where period is 24*3600*1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

24 hours in a day, 60 minutes in an hour, 60 seconds in a minute, 1000 milliseconds in a second

`scheduleAtFixedRate(yourTask, initialDelay, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);`